# GEE: Why era5 data doesn't have 31st of December?

Tags: google-earth-engine

The code is below :

```py
start = ee.Date.fromYMD(1990, 12, 1)
end = ee.Date.fromYMD(1990, 12, 31)

era5_2mt = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY')\
    .select('maximum_2m_air_temperature')\
    .filterDate(start, end)
```

But 31st of December doesn't have data, the output only show 30 elements.

So I would like to know why 31st of December doesn't have data.

Answer (score 5):

31st of December has data, but the `end` parameter of `filterDate` is exclusive. If you want to get data on Dec 31, you need to specify the `end` parameter as `1991, 01, 01`.

[image]